# Free an image that is allocated in a form

Tags: vb.net

I have to load an image and then delete it with another timer, but its not possible unless I release the image resource, the code is:

```
 pic=Image.FromFile(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory+ "s.png")
```

this image is to be replaced by another timer code, but that is not able to replace because I am currently showing this image `s.png`. How can i write `s.png` while showing it and then reload it? Tell me some method by which I can free the resource `s.png` so that other programs can modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reading the image data into memory and creating the `Image` from that:

```
Dim stream = New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() & "s.png"))
Dim pic = Image.FromStream(stream)
```

You will [need to keep the stream open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the lifetime of the `Image`, so when the image file is replaced and you are re-reading it, call `Dispose` on both `stream` and `pic` before recreating them.

Comment: thanx, i got it, i used the syteam and then closed it when i need to change the file, and the image in successfully changed